# implement as constructor parameter on Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, intellij-idea

My BaseFragment looks like

```kotlin
abstract class BaseFragment: Fragment()
    protected abstract val layoutId: Int {
}
```

and I use intellij option `implement as constructor parameter` on my ChildFragment

then My ChildFragment looks like

```kotlin
class ChildFragment(
    override val layoutId: Int = R.layout.fragment_child
) : BaseFragment() {
}
```

and part of `ChildFragment's Java code` has default constructor

```java
   // $FF: synthetic method
   public BestFragment(int var1, int var2, DefaultConstructorMarker var3) {
      if ((var2 & 1) != 0) {
         var1 = -1300103;
      }

      this(var1);
   }

   public BestFragment() {
      this(0, 1, (DefaultConstructorMarker)null);
   }
```

but intellij report an error `Àvoid none default constructors in Fragment`

I thought there was no problem writing `implement as constructor parameter` because it uses Default Constructor, but is this Anti-Pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with non default constructors on Fragments is that they can't be called from XML, and if you rely on it you can't put this Fragment directly in an XML layout.  If you're ok with that restriction, you can do it.  But its a warning because its likely to result in an error if the other people on the project don't understand the limitations.

Adding unique constructors to Views (other than the 3 that already exist) is frowned on for the same reason.